# Django read/write serializer for recursive many-to-many relationship with through field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have a model representing an "Assembly", where one assembly can have any number of sub-assemblies, and for each sub-assembly, it specifies how many instances of that sub-assembly it contains. For example, A contains 1 B and 2 C's, while B contains 1 D, C contains nothing, and D contains nothing. I've represented this in the model like so:

```
from django.db import models

class Assembly(models.Model):
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    subassemblies = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False,
                                           through='AssemblyLink',
                                           through_fields=('parent', 'child'))

class AssemblyLink(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Assembly, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='child_link_set')
    child = models.ForeignKey(Assembly, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='parent_link_set')
    count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()  # Small means <32k
```

and this seems to work, but what I can't figure out is how to write the serializer such that it can read JSON to create a model, and turn the model back into JSON. I'd like to be able to read JSON that looks like:

```
{
    "guid": "GUID123",
    "subassemblies": [
        {"child": "GUID1234", "count": 1}
    ]
}
```

although this format is flexible. Right now my AssemblySerializer looks like this:

```
class AssemblySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subassemblies = ...

    class Meta:
        model = Assembly
        fields = ('guid', 'subassemblies')
```

How should I fill in the ... to make this work?

Comment: I'm dealing with this right now myself.  It's apparently supposed to work out of the box, but I'm about to dig into the `ModelSerializer` source to see if it's missing the ability to handle nested self-referencing or circular-referencing models.  I think the solution may be that we need to write our own views/serializers to return flattened models. [source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-rest-framework/u3DWQKKalm8/FkbAixcm8EQJ)